# Access-Control-Allow-Origin error when trying to invoke Firebase Functions (Even using firebase's example code!)

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Please read, this is different!

I've used Firebase Functions previously and solved this issue by adding this code:

```
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });
return cors(req, res, () => {
    let format = req.query.format;
    if (!format) {
        format = req.body.format;
    }
    const formattedDate = moment().format(format);
    console.log('Sending Formatted date:', formattedDate);
    res.status(200).send(formattedDate);
});
```

But now I'm working on a new project, and I'm getting this error no matter what I try to do.

I have read and tried the solutions in over 20 other questions here on **stackoverflow** and around the internet, and none of them work now.

So I went to firebase's GitHub, downloaded the [date example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/quickstarts/time-server/functions/index.js) (has the recommended cors fix implemented) and deployed it.

And I still get the same error!

```
Access to fetch at 'https://us-central1-generation-y-members.cloudfunctions.net/date' from origin
'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

- The function can be called from postman and does work. https://i.stack.imgur.com/sM470.png
- I've upgraded my project to the blaze plan (didn't help).
- I've tried changing to **origin: "http://localhost:3000"** instead of **origin: true**, didn't help at all.
- I've tried uploading my react app to a server and calling from there, same result (http, not https) - even when setting **origin: "http://my-site.com"**

Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the query being made from the localhost is missing the CORS headers.

On your client side application you need to add the following headers to be able to perform the CORS calls.

```
 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'
 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type'
```

If you are using jav ascript on the client side application this can be done  with the following code, according to the libraries you are using.

```
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
```

Comment: Thank you, it was something else actually. 
I posted the solution I found.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution so I'll post it here for anyone that has the same error and doesn't know why it's happening:

This is the code I'm using now, the issue was not using JSON.stringify() when setting the body for the request.

```
let body: any = {};
body.name = currentUser.name;
body.email = currentUser.email;
body.password = generatedPassword;
body.message = '';
body.number = randomNumber;

const requestOptions: any = {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify(body), // ISSUE WAS HERE! I HAD 'body: body'
};

try {
    let response = await (await fetch('https://us-central1-generation-y-members.cloudfunctions.net/register', requestOptions)).text();
    // let response = await (await fetch('http://localhost:5001/generation-y-members/us-central1/register', requestOptions)).text();

    console.log({ response: response });
    sentEmails.push(currentUser.email);
} catch (e) {
    console.log({ error: e });
}
```

Good luck!